# Custom InputTypes with react-apollo

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to execute a mutation query that requires a custom input type on the client. Currently it looks something like this:

```
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
...
const graphQuery = graphql(gql`
  input UserSignUpInput {
    firstName: String!,
    lastName: String!,
    email: String!,
    password: String!
  }
  mutation userSignUp($input: UserSignUpInput!) {
    createUserByEmail(input: $input) {
      authToken
    }
  }`, {
  props: ({ mutate }) => ({
    signup: (firstName, lastName, email, password) =>
      mutate({ variables: { input: { firstName, lastName, email, password } } }),
  }),
});
...
```

However I'm getting the error that I'm not allowed to define input types in the query. My question is: How do I define these complex input types? It doesn't seem like I'm able to provide a Schema to `ApolloClient`..

Answer (score 13):

The correct syntax on the **client** side is just:

```
gql`
  mutation userSignUp($input: UserSignUpInput!) {
    createUserByEmail(input: $input) {
      authToken
    }
  }
`
```

As your input `UserSignUpInput` is defined on the server, everything is going fine.

*server*

```
input UserSignUpInput {
  firstName: String!,
  lastName: String!,
  email: String!,
  password: String!
}
```

Comment: Where should this input type defined ? In a react app it complains about the syntax !

Comment: If using HotChocolate, be sure to add Input to end of the type name on the Client if you don't have it server. eg is Server type is `UserSignUp`, the Client type will still be `UserSignUpInput`  see [link](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/defining-a-schema/input-object-types#usage)