# @apollo/client (react) Add an array of Objects to a mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I mutation like that, CreateCardDetailInput receives an array of object lile
`type cardDetail { _id: String value: String type: String }`, I want to create mutation and i dont know how to pass array of objects in mutation. thank you in advnace

```
    export const ADD_DEAL = gql`
    mutation createDeal(
        $dealName: String
        $companyName: String
        $cargo: String
        $note: String
        $status: String
        $type: String
        # string (array) argumetns
        $loading: [String!]
        $unloading: [String!]
        $tags: [String!]
        $value: String
        $type: String
        $id: String
    ) {
        createDeal(
            CreateDealInput: {
                dealName: $dealName
                companyName: $companyName
                cargo: $cargo
                note: $note
                status: $status
                type: $type
                # stirng (Array) arguments
                loading: $loading
                unloading: $unloading
                tags: $tags
                CreateCardDetailInput: [{ value: $value, type: $type, _id: $String }]
            }
        )
    }[![graphQL playground screen of endpoint maybe help you][1]][1]
`;
```

Comment: using variables ... https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types ... `$details: [SomeDetailInput]` ... read input type from API playground docs/specs

Comment: Hey Thank you for help, I have a question, can I use input types in apollo client ?

Comment: And If i can can you show me how

Comment: I think maybe i need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622456/custom-inputtypes-with-react-apollo if you look can you agree me if you agree to me

Answer (score 0):

I have Done with code like that thank everyone for help <3

```
mutation createDeal(
    $dealName: String
    $companyName: String
    $cargo: String
    $note: String
    $status: String
    $type: String
    # string (array) argumetns
    $loading: [String!]
    $unloading: [String!]
    $tags: [String!]
    $input: [cardDetail!]
) {
    createDeal(
        CreateDealInput: {
            dealName: $dealName
            companyName: $companyName
            cargo: $cargo
            note: $note
            status: $status
            type: $type
            # stirng (Array) arguments
            loading: $loading
            unloading: $unloading
            tags: $tags
            CreateCardDetailInput: $input
        }
    )
}
```

`;